# time machine cannot pause backup

Tags: backup

I would need to be able to pause my time machine backup and resume it later... however, there is problems:

My backup size is huge, there does not seem to be a way for me to pause it and restart. When I right click, I see:

[image]

if I skip and re-start, it will start from 0.

using System-preference- Time Machine is also no help, no options for pause at all...:

[image]

Since my backup disk is in the office, there needs to be someway i could pause it and re-start... If i just go back to my home and do not use the backup disk at night... then tomorrow morning, I try to resume the back up, it would just fail. Any idea how could I resolve this? Thank you.

Comment: Based on my research there does not appear to be a way to pause your backup progress.  Have you confirmed that, after the first sync, that perhaps future syncs will be faster.?

Comment: the key issue is if the first backup takes 48+ hours.... it never ever finishes.... whenever i am back home... it restarts...

Comment: Voting to close because while this was an issue in 2016, Time Machine has definitely evolved since then an pausing is as simple as ejecting the drive and that’s that. The first backup still takes a long time, but it’s far more stable and reliable nowadays.

Comment: Backups cannot assume your data has not changed, making backups of large datasets difficult to pause because there is not pause, there is only stopping, because there is no restarting, there is only starting over at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can't pause it but you can speed up the process

Deactivate (and later activate) the disk operation throttling so Time Machine will run faster.

Just run on terminal this to deactivate, and when finished use:

```
sudo sysctl debug.lowpri\_throttle_enabled=0
```

And run this to activate it again:

```
sudo sysctl debug.lowpri\_throttle_enabled=1
```